# ¿Autodesplazamiento vertical en TreeView con Scrollbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

¡Buenos días!

He colocado una scrollbar en mi TreeView con tkinter y Python 3.x

¿Es posible hacer que se desplace automáticamente conforme nuevas filas se van generando en el TreeView? ¿O debería ser el TreeView el que deba desplazarse y la Scrollbar limitarse a mostrar la posición?

Os dejo la porción de código donde creo la Scrollbar. (Se que no sigo las convenciones, poco a poco, acabo de leerlas, y ya tenia mucho escrito).

```py
        self.chat = ttk.Treeview(
            frame,
            height=10,
            columns=("#1", "#2", "#3"),
            selectmode="none",
            show="headings"
            )
        self.chat.heading('#1', text='Hora', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.chat.heading("#2", text="Usuario", anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.chat.heading("#3", text="Mensaje", anchor=tk.W)
        self.chat.column("#1", stretch=False, width=50)
        self.chat.column("#2", stretch=False, width=80)
        self.chat.column("#3", stretch=False, width=400)
        self.chat.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        Scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.chat.yview)
        Scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nse")
        self.chat.configure(yscrollcommand=Scrollbar.set)
```

Os muestro una imagen de la aplicación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería bajar, pero permanece ahí. Muchas Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo he entendido, lo que buscas es que al insertar nuevas filas la vista se desplace hacia abajo, de forma que siempre sea visible la ultima linea ingresada.

La forma más simple es que en los métodos en los que insertes items hagas uso del método `tkk.Treeview.see(item)` pasando como el item recién insertado. `ttk.TreeView.insert` retorna el item, por lo que simplemente usa su retorno:

Un ejemplo completo reproducible basado en tu código:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class ChatGui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, *args, user="Yo", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Chat")

        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.chat = ttk.Treeview(
            frame,
            height=10,
            columns=("#1", "#2", "#3"),
            selectmode="none",
            show="headings"
            )
        self.chat.heading('#1', text='Hora', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.chat.heading("#2", text="Usuario", anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.chat.heading("#3", text="Mensaje", anchor=tk.W)
        self.chat.column("#1", stretch=False, width=80)
        self.chat.column("#2", stretch=False, width=80)
        self.chat.column("#3", stretch=True, minwidth=400)
        self.chat.grid(
            row=0, column=0, columnspan=2,
            padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew"
            )

        self.escribir_mensaje = tk.Entry(frame, width=87)
        self.escribir_mensaje.grid(
            row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10
            )
        enviar_mensaje = tk.Button(frame, text="Enviar", command=self.enviar)
        enviar_mensaje.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(
            frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.chat.yview
            )
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nse", pady="10")
        self.chat.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.escribir_mensaje.bind('<Return>', self.enviar)

    def enviar(self, *args):
        msg = self.escribir_mensaje.get()
        if msg:
            self.escribir_mensaje.delete(0, "end")
            hora = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
            item = self.chat.insert("", "end", values=(hora, self.user, msg))
            self.chat.see(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("840x300")
    ChatGui(root, user="FjSevilla").place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]